# Is infinite intersection of any number of subgroups of G is again subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that if H and K are the subgroup of G then $H \cap K$ is again subgroup of G.But what if there are the infinite number of subgroups of G?

Because due to the infinite intersection I not able to use the same argument as in the case of a finite number of intersection of the subgroup is again the subgroup.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can prove this in very much the same fashion as for two subgroups.

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Mathematician 42 As I thought there may be the problem if in case of infinite intersection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because if $\{H_\lambda\,|\,\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is a family of subgroups of $G$ then,

- $e_G\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}H_\lambda$, since $e_G$ belongs to each $H_\lambda$;
- if $h\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}H_\lambda$, then $h^{-1}\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}H_\lambda$, since $h^{-1}$ belongs to each $H_\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true, and yes, the proof is much the same. Let me give you a little taste.

Suppose $G$ is a group, and $(H_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ is a family of subgroups of $G$, over an index set $\Lambda$. The set $\Lambda$ could be finite, countable, uncountable, even empty if you accept the convention of intersection of $0$ subgroups to be $G$. Let $H = \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} H_\alpha$.

Suppose $g, h \in H$. Then, for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$, we have $g, h \in H_\alpha$ (this is from the very definition of intersection of a, possibly infinite, family of sets). Note that $H_\alpha$ is a subgroup, by assumption, hence $gh \in H_\alpha$. This holds true for *all* $\alpha \in \Lambda, so $gh \in H$ (again, from the definition of intersection).

It is very similar to the proof for $2$ cases. It's just that, instead of showing it for $\alpha = 1, 2$, you need to just deal with an arbitrary set of indexes. It's no big deal.